# expanding shell variable in curl POST?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I use the following line to create database:

```
curl -X POST 'http://10.1.1.1:8086/db?u=root&p=root' -d '{name: test1}
```

if i try to do it from shell script:

```
ip=10.1.1.1
curl -X POST 'http://$ip:8086/db?u=root&p=root' -d '{name: test1}'
```

i have a problem with shell variable substitution within single quotas, if i try to use them within double quotas:

```
curl -X POST "http://$ip:8086/db?u=root&p=root" -d '{name: test1}'
```

variable is expanded to the right value, printing in terminal

```
curl -X POST "http://10.1.21.1:8086/db?u=root&p=root" -d '{name: test1}': **No such file or directory**
```

What would be the right solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe I am misreading, but what is your actual question? Why it only works with double quotes?

Comment: How do you use the `curl`? Show the relevant part of your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ip=10.1.1.1
curl -X POST 'http://'"$ip"':8086/db?u=root&p=root' -d '{name: test1}'
```

Comment: this works, better even: curl -X POST 'http://'"$ip"':8086/db?u=root&p=root' -d '{name: test1}'